# Is there any possibility to download an image in TYPO3 instead of showing it

Tags: image, typo3

Is the a possibility in TYPO3 to download photos instead of showing them in the browser?
the attribute download works only with very new browser but not with IE11...

I just want to use f.e. dce to show some thumbs and download the complete photo

Thanks
Volker

Answer (score 2):

IMHO this is nothing TYPO3 specific. 
The real question is: "How to let the browser download an image instead of displaying it"

To achieve this, you need to link that thumbnail to a PHP script passing some kind of identifier of the image you want to push to the browser, instead of to the link to the large version of the image.

You can achieve this by configuring the DCE approprietly.

This PHP script then needs to read the image file from disk and push it tho the client tweeking some HTTP headers.

E.g. something like this.

```
    @ob_end_clean(); //turn off output buffering to decrease cpu usage

    $filePath = '/some/path/to/an_image.jpg';

    // deliver the file
    if (is_file($filePath))
    {
      // required for IE, otherwise Content-Disposition may be ignored
     if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
        ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');

     header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
     header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($filePath) . '"');
     header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
     header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
     header("Cache-control: no-cache, pre-check=0, post-check=0");
     header("Cache-control: private");
     header('Pragma: private');
     header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");

     $size = filesize($filePath);
     header("Content-Length: ".$size);

     // pass the file to the client
     readfile($filePath);

  } else die('Error - can not open file.');

  die();
```

Answer (score 2):

We used a different approach in one of our projects. We prefixed the URL to the image with eg. "binary" and defined the appropriate header in the apache configuration:

```
Alias /binary "PATH/TO/WEBROOT/uploads/pics" 

<Location /binary>
    ForceType application/octet-stream
    Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</Location>
```

So you can place the images in uploads/pics and if you retrieve them via binary/uploads/pics the browser is forced to download them. You can use the original URL as well.

Comment: This is very nice possible solution. I must keep that in mind.